# Ruby Method Chaining

Tags: ruby, chaining, method-chaining

I would like to chain my own methods in Ruby. Instead of writing ruby methods and using them like this:

```
def percentage_to_i(percentage)
  percentage.chomp('%')
  percentage.to_i
end

percentage = "75%"
percentage_to_i(percentage)
=> 75
```

I would like to use it like this:

```
percentage = "75%"
percentage.percentage_to_i
=> 75
```

How can I achieve  this?

Comment: Why not make a `Percent` class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to add the method to the String class:

```
class String
  def percentage_to_i
    self.chomp('%')
    self.to_i
  end
end
```

With this you can get your desired output:

```
percentage = "75%"
percentage.percentage_to_i # => 75
```

It's kind of useless, because `to_i` does it for you already:

```
percentage = "75%"
percentage.to_i # => 75
```

Comment: Haha I ended up doing this and coming back to write my own answer. Waiting to accept yours. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, the question was more about chaining but I did not know that I could do the same thing with `to_i` alone.

Comment: I added the method to the `String` class (as in your answer), but in a model file (`app/models/content.rb`), after that model's class definition's `end` statement. I think doing so is called "mixin".

Answer (score 1):

It's not completely clear what you want.

If you want to be able to convert an instance of String to_i, then just call to_i:

```
"75%".to_i  => 75
```

If you want it to have some special behavior, then monkey patch the String class:

```
class String
    def percentage_to_i
        self.to_i    # or whatever you want
    end
end
```

And if you truly want to chain methods, then you typically want to return a modified instance of the same class.

```
class String
    def half
        (self.to_f / 2).to_s
    end
end

s = "100"
s.half.half   => "25"
```

Answer (score 0):

Singleton methods

```
def percentage.percentage_to_i
  self.chomp('%')
  self.to_i
end
```

creating your own class

```
class Percent
  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end

  def to_i
    @value.chomp('%')
    @value.to_i
  end

  def to_s
    "#{@value}%"
  end
end
```

Comment: Interesting, when would this be more advantageous than extending the class? I'm trying to figure out a use-case for the extra work involved with Singleton methods?

Comment: @Dru Singleton methods on instances are useful when they're one-off things. I've used them when I need to morph an object to an API for use in a library function, but they're not needed very often.

Comment: When there is actually only one instance that you need a different behavior that's not defined in the class. The good thing about it is that you don't have to change the class nor extending it.