# ruby method chaining for arbitrary objects, classes

Tags: ruby, chain

I often find myself writing ruby code that looks like this:

```
b = f1(a)
c = f2(b)
d = f3(c)
...
```

Is there a way to chain `f1`, `f2`, `f3` together regardless of the types of a, b, and c?  For examplesomething like

```
a.send_to(&:f1)
  .sent_to(&:f2)
  .sent_to(&:f3)
```

It doesn't need to be exactly that, but I like the code that can be read, in order, as "start with `a`, now apply `f1`, then apply `f2`, ..."

It occurs to me that all I'm really asking for here is a way to use `map` on a single object rather than a list.  E.g. I could do this:

```
[a].map(&:f1)
  .map(&:f2)
  .map(&:f3)
  .first
```

The following (sort of) works, though monkey-patching `Object` seems like a bad idea:

```
class Object
  def send_to(&block)
    block.call(self)
  end  
end
```

I say "(sort of) works" because

```
1.send_to{|x| x+1}
#=> 2
```

but

```
def add_1(x); x+1; end  
1.send_to(&:add_1)
#=> NoMethodError: private method `add_1' called for 0:Fixnum
```

Note: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360051/ruby-method-chaining) asks something similar, but the proposal is to define a method on the particular class of each object.

Comment: What do you mean by “chaining”? Do you need dots (`.`). Do you care about order: `a.f1.f2`, `f2.f1.a`. Does one of order preferable or are both ok?

Comment: Am I missing something? What's wrong with `f3(f2(f1(a)))`?

Comment: @meagar - f3(f2(f1(a)) will do in a pinch, but esp. when there are many more fN's, it's much easier for others to follow when the operations are in order, so it can be read as "start with `a`, then apply `f1`, then apply `f2`, ..."

Comment: @Darek Nędza - good point; just edited the question to (hopefully) clarify the desired properties.

Comment: @brahn I agree, that's why the way it's currently written in the question is *already* the best way. None of the upvoted solutions below should *ever* exist in a real codebase, they're adding a hugely opaque layer of WTF to a simple series of function invocations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby 2.5's `.yield_self` does exactly this!
https://zverok.github.io/blog/2018-01-24-yield_self.html

And if I follow this discussion correctly, `.then` is now a please alias for `.yield_self`
https://www.reddit.com/r/ruby/comments/8nfqmt/kernelthen_is_now_an_alias_for_kernelyield_self/

Answer (score 6):

You can do as :

```
d = [:f1, :f2, :f3].inject(a) { |res,f| send(f, res) }
```

Comment: @archie Of course it would. The better question is, does it matter?

Answer (score 4):

I think basically what you want is a combination of inject and send. Something like:

```
d = [:f1, :f2, :f3].inject(a) {|memo, fun| send(fun, memo) }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you feel the necessity of doing that frequently, then your API design is wrong as a Ruby code. Rather than defining methods in function style:

```
b = f1(a)
c = f2(b)
d = f3(c)
...
```

define them in OOP style:

```
class A
  def f1; ... end # => b instance
end
class B
  def f2; ... end # => c instance
end
class C
  def f3; ... end # => d instance
end
```

Here, `A` is the class that `a` belongs to, `B` is the class that `b` belongs to, and so on (`A`, `B`, ... do not have to be all different. They can be `Object` or `Kernel` if you want to allow any object). Then, you can simply do chaining as:

```
a.f1.f2.f3. ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you start with `f3` function you don’t need to change anything.
Secondly, ability to omit parenthesis is great.

For example:

```
a = 42

def f1 n; n end

def f2 n; n end

def f3 n; n end

f3 f2 f1 a

# => 42
```

With more complex functions you may add parenthesis.